# YouTube iframe embeds are not working on my iPhone and iPad 3

Tags: html, ios, youtube, mobile-safari

http://jsfiddle.net/Dqc39/1/

I'm trying to play YouTube embeds using iFrames on my iPad and iPhone. However, whenever I click the iframe, the only thing that happens is that the iframe flickers. Clicking the title doesn't even bring me to the YouTube page.

However, when I go to http://reddit.com/r/videos, clicking any of the embeds there works fine. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using the [HTML5 iframe embed](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html)? You need to add [`[type="text/html"]`](http://jsfiddle.net/Dqc39/2/)

Comment: hoped that was the solution, but it still doesn't work. i'd like to just add that clicking the title link doesn't work either. updated: http://jsfiddle.net/Dqc39/3/

Comment: fyi guys, it was one of the query options. i forgot which, but i just removed them all and it works fine now.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

it was one of the query options. i forgot which, but i just removed them all and it works fine now

Comment: Did you find out _which_ one?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the `Embed` tag. That might work because sometimes the `iframe` tag causes problems for the browsers.